Issue with Coolbox and matplotlib dependencies
Yesterday I was working in jupyter notebook with Coolbox dependency on my HiC data and everything was working fine. Today when I try to import neccessary dependencies I keep getting error after passing: "import coolbox
from coolbox.api import"
And the error goes as follows: "ImportError: cannot import name 'BrokenBarHCollection' from 'matplotlib.collections' (/home/phronek/miniconda3/envs/coolbox_env_3_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py)"
[I am sending screenshot of the issue so you can see the full error report]
(https://i.sstatic.net/nu3ehHPN.png)
Any ideas how to fix it please?
I reinstalled both coolbox and matplotlib, I tried using different versions but nothing worked.
I didnt update anything this morning but even after reinstalling all those dependencies, the error prevails.
